# Create lag variable based on custom condition in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to create :

1. a lag of the previous of variable based on a previous time a random event happened (Eg. no fixed days between events so dplyr::lag() function by itself won't work
2. be able to pull in the variables associated with the last two or three times this happened and take the average of those variables

Below is  sample dataset using the mtcars package

Translating the above request to example dataframe below,

1. I'd like to bring in a new column the mpg value that that was last associated with the previous random event in the current random event (eg lag mpg but only take from the previous time the random event indicator occurred) -- for the other days the isn't a random event put 0
2. On a day random event occur looked to the last two times a random event occurred and take the  mpg values of those previous random events and return the average of those mpgs in the current random event position.

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(123)
rows <- sample(1:nrow(mtcars),4,)

df <- mtcars %>% 
  mutate(
    event_id=row_number()
    ,random_event=if_else(event_id %in% rows,1,0)
  )
``
```

Comment: Hi, it is a bit hard to understand what you are trying to do. Can you manually create the resulting table you anticipate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can solve your problem using `lag` function, you just need to configure the `order_by` parameter. Note that I just changed the variable `random_event` to `1` if the random event occurred and `NA` otherwise to get rid of the problem of initial values having no previous value(s).

**Problem 1**

```
  df1 <- df %>%
          select(mpg, event_id, random_event) %>% 
          mutate(mpg_r = ifelse(random_event == 1, lag(mpg, order_by = random_event), 0),
                 mpg_r = replace_na(mpg_r, 0))
```

**Problem 2**

```
  df2 <- df %>%
          select(mpg, event_id, random_event) %>% 
          mutate(mpg_m = (ifelse(random_event == 1, lag(mpg, n = 1, order_by = random_event), 0) + 
                          ifelse(random_event == 1, lag(mpg, n = 2, order_by = random_event), 0)) / 2,
                 mpg_m = replace_na(mpg_m, 0))
```

In practice the `order_by = random_event` parameter internally arranges your dataframe by the random event occurrence so it makes it possible to the `lag` fucntion to get the correct value needed.